# Adding package from non-standard ELPA Repository to Layer

Tags: package, spacemacs, package-repositories

So I have a package I would like to add from an ELPA repository different than MELPA. The repository is called "billpiel" and the link is http://billpiel.com/emacs-packages/. I would like to add the package `sayid` to a layer (specifically the clojure layer, though that is unimportant). How would I do this in spacemacs?

I've tried adding this line to the top of the layer file, to my `user-init` method and to the `dot-spacemacs/layers` method (I know, I shouldn't): `(add-to-list 'configuration-layer--elpa-archives '("billpiel" . "http://billpiel.com/emacs-packages/"))` and then installing the sayid package as an additional package but that didn't work.

Trying to add the package as `(sayid :location "http://billpiel.com/emacs-packages/")` also failed.

The package documentation is here: https://bpiel.github.io/sayid/. How can I add this package to a layer in a way that I can distribute the layer?